# SQL Server : Insert Trigger for Multi-Tenant Default Entries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have a table of products that is shared across all tenants. Each tenant can, however, have their own ratings for each product stored in the `ProductRating` table. When new products are inserted into the `Product` table, I want a trigger to insert a default rating, for each tenant, into the `ProductRating` table for each product inserted.

I am thinking this isn't as difficult as my brain is making it, but I just can't get it.

Any help is appreciated.

For simplicity:

```
|-----------------------|
|       Tenant          |
|-----------------------|
| TenantId | TenantName |
|-----------------------|

|--------------------------|
|         Product          |
|--------------------------|
| Product ID | ProductName |
|--------------------------|

|-------------------------------|
|          ProductRating        |
|-------------------------------|
| TenantId | ProductId | Rating |
|-------------------------------|
```

J

Comment: Just out of curiosity, @marc_s, why are you offended by Title Case in the post title?

Comment: It's a title. If you want it to be a sentence, then you should have added punctuation. :o)

Comment: Why give me an attitude? You started it by performing unnecessary edits to a post you didn't even provide a solution for. I don't think I was being rude with my queries as to your edits. And proper title case, as my original post contained, would not capitalize the word "for".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will need at least two triggers - one for when a product is added to give it a default rating for all existing tenants, and one for when a new tenant is added to give it a default rating for all existing products.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DefaultRatingsByNewTenant ON Tenant
FOR INSERT

AS

Begin

    INSERT into ProductRating(TenantID, ProductID, Rating)

    SELECT
        i.TenantID
        , p.ProductID
        , 5 as defaultRating
    FROM
        inserted i
        cross join Product p

end
```

and the other is easy enough to work out from there...

```
CREATE TRIGGER DefaultRatingsByNewProduct ON Product
FOR INSERT

AS

Begin

    INSERT into ProductRating(TenantID, ProductID, Rating)

    SELECT
        t.TenantID
        , i.ProductID
        , 5 as defaultRating
    FROM
        inserted i
        cross join tenant t

end
```

Comment: Thank you, @Greenspark. I knew I was making it more complicated that it needed to be.